# Grails Tika Plugin - How do I send a file from a database to tika to parse

Tags: grails, io, apache-tika

I've used [this example](http://grails.asia/grails-example-application-save-documents-to-database) to upload and download a file to the database. 
How can I, then, send that file to `TikaService` I have and parse the data?

The tutorial saves the `filename` and `filedata` separately. `filedata` is binary data.

I can parse a file within the app folder fine but I need to bring a file from the database.

OR, can I parse a file without saving it to the database?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT - Error**

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /myApp/document/parse/8
No such property: inputstream for class: com.myApp.DocumentController. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: inputstream for class: com.myApp.DocumentController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache Tika `parse()` method uses an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) as input. Since the `filedata` is a `byte` array, you can use a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to provide the file data from your domain class to Apache Tika.

```
def doc = Document.read(/*some id*/)
def inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.filedata)
def parser = /* Your Apache Tika parser */
def handler = /* An implementation of org.xml.sax.ContentHandler */
def metadata = new org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata()

parser.parse(inputStream, handler, metadata)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry for getting back late. I tried and I'm getting some `missing property errors` Could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: You've got a typo. Make sure the `inputStream` variable is spelled consistently.

Comment: Oh, man. That was quite silly. Thanks for pointing it out. It works now.